# Solve Linear Sytem of Equation for $u,v,w$

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I need to solve this sytem for $u,v,w$. I´ve tried basic algebra, but my answer does not mach the one from the book.

[image: Solve for u, v, w]

Comment: Please show your answer and the book answer.  With that, we can tell which is right.  It may well be that the book is wrong.  Basic algebra should work, and you can check your solution by back substituting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way (unless this is a course on using matrix methods) is to sequentially substitute:
$$
\vec{u} = \vec{a} - \vec{w} 
$$
$$
\vec{b} = 2\vec{u} + \vec{v} - \vec{w} = 2\vec{a} +  \vec{v} - 3\vec{w} \longrightarrow \vec{v} = \vec{b} - 2\vec{a} +  3\vec{w}
$$
$$
\vec{c} = \vec{v} - 2\vec{w} = \vec{b} - 2\vec{a} +  \vec{w} \longrightarrow \vec{w}  = \vec{c} - \vec{b} + 2\vec{a}
$$
And having found $\vec{w}$ back-substitute:
$$
\vec{w}  = 2\vec{a} - \vec{b} + \vec{c} 
$$
$$
\vec{v} = \vec{b} - 2\vec{a} +  3\vec{w} = 4\vec{a} -2\vec{b} + 3\vec{c} 
$$ 
$$
\vec{u} = \vec{a} - \vec{w} = -\vec{a} + \vec{b} -\vec{c}
$$

You should check that this solves the equations by plugging this in.

Answer (score 1):

You can write it as a matrix multiplication

$$ \begin{bmatrix}\vec{a} & \vec{b} & \vec{c} \end{bmatrix}^\top = 
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 2 & 1 & -1 \\ 0 & 1 & -2 \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}\vec{u} & \vec{v} & \vec{w} \end{bmatrix}^\top $$

$$  \begin{bmatrix} a_x & a_y & a_z \\ b_x & b_y & b_z \\ c_x & c_y & c_z \end{bmatrix}= 
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 2 & 1 & -1 \\ 0 & 1 & -2 \end{bmatrix}  \begin{bmatrix} u_x & u_y & u_z \\ v_x & v_y & v_z \\ w_x & w_y & w_z \end{bmatrix} $$

$$  \begin{bmatrix} a_x & a_y & a_z \\ b_x & b_y & b_z \\ c_x & c_y & c_z \end{bmatrix}=  \begin{bmatrix}
u_x+w_x & u_y+w_y & u_z + w_z \\
2 u_x+v_x-w_x & 2 u_y+v_y-w_y &2 u_z+v_z-w_z \\
v_x -2 w_x &v_y -2 w_y & v_z -2 w_z
\end{bmatrix} \checkmark$$

$$ \begin{bmatrix} u_x & u_y & u_z \\ v_x & v_y & v_z \\ w_x & w_y & w_z \end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 2 & 1 & -1 \\ 0 & 1 & -2 \end{bmatrix}^{-1} \begin{bmatrix} a_x & a_y & a_z \\ b_x & b_y & b_z \\ c_x & c_y & c_z \end{bmatrix} $$

$$ \begin{bmatrix} u_x & u_y & u_z \\ v_x & v_y & v_z \\ w_x & w_y & w_z \end{bmatrix}
= \begin{bmatrix}-1 & 1 & -1 \\ 4 & -2 & 3 \\ 2 & -1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} a_x & a_y & a_z \\ b_x & b_y & b_z \\ c_x & c_y & c_z \end{bmatrix}
$$

$$\begin{bmatrix} u_x & u_y & u_z \\ v_x & v_y & v_z \\ w_x & w_y & w_z \end{bmatrix}
= \begin{bmatrix}
-a_x+b_x-c_x & -a_y+b_y-c_y & -a_z+b_z-c_z \\
4 a_x -2 b_x+3 c_x &4 a_y -2 b_y+3 c_y & 4 a_z -2 b_z+3 c_z \\
2 a_x - b_x+ c_x & 2 a_y - b_y+ c_y & 2 a_z - b_z+ c_z \end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: It's entirely superfluous to treat the components of $\vec{a}$, $\vec{b}$, and $\vec{c}$ separately. You can just treat them as scalars and still reach the correct solution.

Comment: This was just for illustrative purposes actually.