# How could we calculate the final weight, knowing the initial and final water percentage, and initial weight‽??

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, arithmetic, integers

I am doing the math exercise by hand before starting to write an answer for the following programming exercise: [Drying potatoes](https://www.codewars.com/kata/58ce8725c835848ad6000007). The statement is:

> All we eat is water and dry matter.
>
> John bought potatoes: their weight is 100 kilograms. Potatoes contain
>   water and dry matter.
>
> The water content is 99 percent of the total weight. He thinks they
>   are too wet and puts them in an oven - at low temperature - for them
>   to lose some water.
>
> At the output the water content is only 98%.
>
> What is the total weight in kilograms (water content plus dry matter)
>   coming out of the oven?
>
> He finds 50 kilograms and he thinks he made a mistake: "So much weight
>   lost for such a small change in water content!"
>
> Can you help him?
>
> Write function potatoes with
>
> ```
> int parameter p0 - initial percent of water-
> int parameter w0 - initial weight -
> int parameter p1 - final percent of water -
> ```
>
> potatoesshould return the final weight coming out of the oven w1
>   truncated as an int. Example:
>
> potatoes(99, 100, 98) --> 50

I am trying to understand how can we solve by hand this exercise. I have tried the rule of 3:

- initial percentage of water -> initial weight
- final percentage of water -> x (final weight)

x = ( initial percentage of water - initial weight ) / final percentage of water;

x = 99 - 100 / 98 = -1 / 98 = -0,0102 (and it should be 50)...

Then I tried to use a linear equation as:

initial water percentage - final water percentage = initial weight - final weight (x); 99 - 98 = 100 - x; 99 - 98 - 100 = -x; x = 99 (and it should be 50)...

I have also observed the exercise's test cases where p0: initial water percentage, w0: initial weight, p1: final water percentage, w1: final weight (what we should be able to calculate)

- p0, w0, p1, w1
- 82, 127, 80, 114
- 93, 129, 91, 100

In addition I have also read:

- [Solving linear equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1794593/solving-linear-equation)
- [What is a linear equation?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1031250/what-is-a-linear-equation)
- [Solve Linear Sytem of Equation for $u,v,w$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/803237/solve-linear-sytem-of-equation-for-u-v-w)
- https://www.purplemath.com/modules/systlin1.htm
- https://www.wtamu.edu/academic/anns/mps/math/mathlab/int_algebra/int_alg_tut7_lineq.htm

How could we calculate the final weight, knowing the initial water percentage, final water percentage, and initial weight‽??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define:
\begin{align*}
d &= \text{dry mass (both before and after)} \\
p_0 &= \text{initial water percentage} \\
p_1 &= \text{final water percentage} \\
w_0 &= \text{initial water mass} \\
w_0 &= \text{final water mass} \\
t_0 &= \text{initial total mass} \\
t_1 &= \text{final total mass}
\end{align*}
Then we have:
\begin{cases}
\dfrac{p_0}{100} = \dfrac{w_0}{w_0 + d} = \dfrac{w_0}{t_0} \\
\dfrac{p_1}{100} = \dfrac{w_1}{w_1 + d} = \dfrac{w_1}{t_1}
\end{cases}

Given $p_0, t_0, p_1$, we want to find $t_1$. To this end, observe that:
\begin{align*}
\dfrac{p_0}{100} = \dfrac{w_0}{t_0} &\implies \boxed{w_0 = t_0 \cdot \frac{p_0}{100}} \\
t_0 = d + w_0 &\implies \boxed{d = t_0 - w_0} \\
\dfrac{p_1}{100} = \dfrac{w_1}{w_1 + d} \implies p_1w_1 + p_1d = 100w_1 &\implies \boxed{w_1 = \frac{p_1d}{100 - p_1}}
\end{align*}

Putting it together, we find that:
$$
t_1 = d + w_1 = \left(1 + \frac{p_1}{100 - p_1} \right) \cdot t_0 \left(1 - \frac{p_0}{100} \right)
= t_0 \cdot \left( \frac{100 - p_0}{100 - p_1} \right)
$$
Indeed, for the first test case, we see that:
$$
t_1 = 100 \cdot \left( \frac{100 - 99}{100 - 98} \right) = 50
$$

Comment: Your answer is correct, I have programmed it in Java and it gives as the desired output. In addition I have seen a more simple solution, from the answers given to the programming task: w0 * (100 - p0) / (100 - p1) 